# Why there is a huge gap in performance(in terms of time taken) when I use Stream API twice in Java 8?

Tags: java-8, java-stream

In the below example, countOdds() takes around 23ms & countEven() takes around 1ms. Even if I create a copy of countOdds() & call second time, that takes 1ms only. I want to understand why that is happening ?

**Output**:
Number of odd numbers is 5
Time taken is 23ms
No of even numbers is 5
Time taken is 1ms

**Example**
public class Sol {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("Number of odd numbers is " + new Sol().countOdds(9, 17));//3
    long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("Time taken is "+ (endTime-startTime) +"ms");
    
    long startTimeAnother = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("No of even numbers is " + new Sol().countEven(21, 30));
    long endTimeAnother = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("Time taken is "+ (endTimeAnother-startTimeAnother) +"ms");
}
public int countOdds(int low, int high) {
    return (int) IntStream.rangeClosed(low, high).filter(n -> n%2!=0).count();
               
}

public int countEven(int low, int high) {
    return (int) IntStream.rangeClosed(low, high).filter(n -> n%2==0).count();
               
}
```

}

Comment: Testing method is essential. Try to check on multiple runs, say 1000.(make individuals test, for each methods in the same conditions, use larger intervals, etc) Timing should be almost the same.

Comment: Most likely you’re just benchmarking the class loader.

Comment: Thanks @TraianGEICU, when I am trying with larger intervals , it returns almost same timing.